# Php soap sending data

Tags: php, soap

Can anyone help me to understand how to send the soap:envelop to a web service server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the SOAP client library: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php
If you are using it already, then you will need to provide a more detailed explanation for the problem you are running into.